# Eloquent Date Query

Tags: date, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table (with soft delete) and it is a whats on table. There is a field which is just a date field with the start date.

What I am trying to do is use eloquent to get a list of what on today onwards, but my attempts throw an error:

```
$wo = App\WhatsOn::whereDate('startDate', '=>', date('Y-m-d') )->get();
```

The error I am getting is

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> ? and `whatson`.`deleted_at` is null' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `whatson` where date(`startDate`) => 2019-05-05 and `whatson`.`deleted_at` is null)

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. It should be

` $wo = App\WhatsOn::whereDate('startDate', '>=', date('Y-m-d') )->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$wo = App\WhatsOn::whereDate('startDate', '>=', date('Y-m-d') )->get();
```

Dumb mistake!